# Trying Ruby: why can't I install nanoc?

Tags: ruby

I try to install nanoc http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/2-installation/

by typing in irb

```
gem install nano
```

it says undefined variable or method 'nanoc' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install it from the shell, not IRB.  Gem is a command, i.e.

`% which gem`

`/usr/bin/gem`

`% gem install nanoc`

ian.

Answer (score 1):

That `gem install` command is meant to be run in your normal system shell (something like Bash, for example).

`irb` is a Ruby shell, it interactively executes Ruby code. You'll notice that the instructions you link to immediately tell you to quit `irb` after starting it (they only told you to run it to make sure Ruby was installed).